# pos_weight in multilabel classification in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, multilabel-classification, pytorch-lightning

I am using pytorch for multilabel classification. I have used pos_weights in BCELoss since i have imbalanced data. FOr to use pos_weight, whether we need to take the entire dataset(train, validation, test) or only the training set for calculating the pos_Weight... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

While not a coding question and better suited for a different SE site, the quick answer is this:

You always assume you have never seen the test set before, so you cannot use it in any way to make decisions about the model design. For the validation set, a similar argument can be made in that you want to validate at regular intervals using unseen data. As such, you want to calculate class weights using the train data only.

Do keep in mind that if the class distribution is not a representation of the class distribution in unseen data (i.e. the real world, or your test set), then the model will optimize for the wrong class distribution. This should be solved by analyzing the task better, not by directly using the test set to determine class distribution.